Background Notification Click
I'm working on an Android app where I need to open the last interacted screen when the user clicks on a notification while the app is in the background. However, instead of resuming the last activity, the app launches from SplashActivity every time, even though the last activity (e.g., HomeActivity) was open before the app was backgrounded.
<activity
            android:name="com.example.ajio.domain.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoWindowBackground"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="something.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/suiretiy" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Notification receiver class
val onboardingIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            //flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            putExtra(IntentData.KEY_NOTIFICATION_BODY, bundle)
        }
val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(title")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
            //.setSound(notificationSound)
            .setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(bundle))

Expected behaviour
While clicking notifications and app in the background need to open last screen without launching splash.
current behavoir
Whenever i click notification while app is background its tarting from the splashscreen.

Try to put single top flag to the intent
